# __android_log_print printing with out '/n' newline CR

Tags: android, c, logging, printf, native

WHen in native code `__android_log_print()` is used it prints adds an `/n` at the end of the text.

I am trying to get the same behavior as `printf`, where when `/n` not used it prints the next sting on the same line.

I need to write a data dump so I need to be able to to structure the data. 
Now, I know I can store things in a temp buffer but I don't want to do that.

As I am working on an embedded device with an extremely small runtime memory.

Comment: First you need to learn the difference between a slash and a backslash...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider whether the `__android_log_print()` function is appropriate to use for dumping data. It's conventional for logging functions that they output whole lines for each call.

Comment: Yeah I actually dump the whole thing to a file.